# New Custom Widget Call a Different Widget Function

Tags: widgets

My theme includes a widget for showing tweets. I want to take this widget and create my own version of it. I have successfully created a new widget listing in the admin but the widget functions from the other file is still being called when the front end is rendered. I confirmed this by putting an echo in the widget() function of the new widget.

See links below for the code for each file:

**Original Theme Widget:** Full Code - http://pastebin.com/asprtK6h

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'penci_latest_tweets_load_widget' );

function penci_latest_tweets_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'penci_latest_tweets_widget' );
}

class penci_latest_tweets_widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Widget setup.
     */
    function penci_latest_tweets_widget() {
        /* Widget settings. */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'penci_latest_tweets_widget', 'description' => esc_html__('A widget that displays your latest tweets with a slider', 'soledad') );

        /* Widget control settings. */
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 250, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'penci_latest_tweets_widget' );

        /* Create the widget. */
        global $wp_version;
        if( 4.3 > $wp_version ) {
            $this->WP_Widget( 'penci_latest_tweets_widget', esc_html__('.Soledad Tweets Slider', 'soledad'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
        } else {
            parent::__construct( 'penci_latest_tweets_widget', esc_html__('.Soledad Tweets Slider', 'soledad'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
        }
    }

    /**
     * How to display the widget on the screen.
     */
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        /* Our variables from the widget settings. */
        $title    = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $date     = isset( $instance['date'] ) ? $instance['date'] : false;
        $auto     = isset( $instance['auto'] ) ? $instance['auto'] : false;
        $reply    = isset( $instance['reply'] ) ? $instance['reply'] : esc_html__( 'Reply', 'soledad' );
        $retweet  = isset( $instance['retweet'] ) ? $instance['retweet'] : esc_html__( 'Retweet', 'soledad' );
        $favorite = isset( $instance['favorite'] ) ? $instance['favorite'] : esc_html__( 'Favorite', 'soledad' );

        $tweets = getTweets(5);

        if( !empty( $tweets ) ):

            /* Before widget (defined by themes). */
            echo ent2ncr( $before_widget );

            /* Display the widget title if one was input (before and after defined by themes). */
            if ( $title )
                echo ent2ncr( $before_title . $title . $after_title );

            if( isset( $tweets['error'] ) ) {
                echo 'Missing consumer key - please check your settings in admin > Settings > Twitter Feed Auth';
            } else {
            ?>
            <div class="penci-tweets-widget-content">
                <span class="icon-tweets"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
                <div class="penci-slider penci-tweets-slider" data-smooth="true" data-direction="horizontal" data-auto="<?php if( $auto ){ echo 'false'; } else { echo 'true'; } ?>" data-dir="true" data-control="false" data-autotime="5000" data-speed="500">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <?php foreach( $tweets as $tweet ):
                        $date_array = explode( ' ', $tweet['created_at'] );
                        $tweet_id = $tweet['id_str'];
                        $tweet_text = $tweet['text'];
                        $urls = $tweet['entities']['urls'];

                        if( isset( $urls ) ) {
                            foreach ( $urls as $ul ) {
                                $url = $ul['url'];
                                if( isset( $url ) ):
                                    $tweet_text = str_replace( $url, '<a href="'. $url .'" target="_blank">'. $url .'</a>', $tweet_text );
                                endif;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                            <li class="penci-tweet">
                                <div class="tweet-text">
                                    <?php echo $tweet_text; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php if( $date_array[1] && $date_array[2] && $date_array[5] && ! $date ): ?>
                                <p class="tweet-date"><?php echo $date_array[2] . '-' . $date_array[1] . '-' . $date_array[5]; ?></p>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <div class="tweet-intents">
                                    <div class="tweet-intents-inner">
                                        <span><a target="_blank" class="reply" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=<?php echo sanitize_text_field( $tweet_id ); ?>"><?php echo sanitize_text_field( $reply ); ?></a></span>
                                        <span><a target="_blank" class="retweet" href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=<?php echo sanitize_text_field( $tweet_id ); ?>"><?php echo sanitize_text_field( $retweet ); ?></a></span>
                                        <span><a target="_blank" class="favorite" href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=<?php echo sanitize_text_field( $tweet_id ); ?>"><?php echo sanitize_text_field( $favorite ); ?></a></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            }
        endif; /* End check if array $tweets empty or null */

        /* After widget (defined by themes). */
        echo ent2ncr( $after_widget );
    }
}
```

**New Widget:** Full Code - http://pastebin.com/wQ839BNF
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'sjcny_latest_tweets_load_widget' );

```
function sjcny_latest_tweets_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'sjcny_latest_tweets_widget' );
}

class sjcny_latest_tweets_widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Widget setup.
     */
    function sjcny_latest_tweets_widget() {
        /* Widget settings. */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'sjcny_latest_tweets_widget', 'description' => esc_html__('A widget that displays your latest tweets with a slider', 'soledad') );

        /* Widget control settings. */
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 250, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'sjcny_latest_tweets_widget' );

        /* Create the widget. */
        global $wp_version;
        if( 4.3 > $wp_version ) {
            $this->WP_Widget( 'sjcny_latest_tweets_widget', esc_html__('SJCNY Tweets Slider', 'soledad'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
        } else {
            parent::__construct( 'sjcny_latest_tweets_widget', esc_html__('SJCNY Tweets Slider', 'soledad'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
        }
    }

    /**
     * How to display the widget on the screen.
     */
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo "asdf1234";
        extract( $args );

        /* Our variables from the widget settings. */
        $title    = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $date     = isset( $instance['date'] ) ? $instance['date'] : false;
        $auto     = isset( $instance['auto'] ) ? $instance['auto'] : false;
        $reply    = isset( $instance['reply'] ) ? $instance['reply'] : esc_html__( 'Reply', 'soledad' );
        $retweet  = isset( $instance['retweet'] ) ? $instance['retweet'] : esc_html__( 'Retweet', 'soledad' );
        $favorite = isset( $instance['favorite'] ) ? $instance['favorite'] : esc_html__( 'Favorite', 'soledad' );

        $tweets = getTweets(5);

        //if( !empty( $tweets ) ):
    if( true ) :

            /* Before widget (defined by themes). */
            echo ent2ncr( $before_widget );

            /* Display the widget title if one was input (before and after defined by themes). */
            if ( $title )
                echo ent2ncr( $before_title . $title . $after_title );

            if( isset( $tweets['error'] ) ) {
                echo 'Missing consumer key - please check your settings in admin > Settings > Twitter Feed Auth';
            } else {
            ?>
            <div class="penci-tweets-widget-content">
                <span class="icon-tweets"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
                <div class="penci-slider penci-tweets-slider" data-smooth="true" data-direction="horizontal" data-auto="<?php if( $auto ){ echo 'false'; } else { echo 'true'; } ?>" data-dir="true" data-control="false" data-autotime="5000" data-speed="500">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <?php foreach( $tweets as $tweet ):
                        $date_array = explode( ' ', $tweet['created_at'] );
                        $tweet_id = $tweet['id_str'];
                        $tweet_text = $tweet['text'];
                        $urls = $tweet['entities']['urls'];

                        if( isset( $urls ) ) {
                            foreach ( $urls as $ul ) {
                                $url = $ul['url'];
                                if( isset( $url ) ):
                                    $tweet_text = str_replace( $url, '<a href="'. $url .'" target="_blank">'. $url .'</a>', $tweet_text );
                                endif;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                            <li class="penci-tweet">
                                <div class="tweet-text">
                                    <?php echo $tweet_text; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php if( $date_array[1] && $date_array[2] && $date_array[5] && ! $date ): ?>
                                <p class="tweet-date"><?php echo $date_array[2] . '-' . $date_array[1] . '-' . $date_array[5]; ?></p>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <div class="tweet-intents">
                                    <div class="tweet-intents-inner">
                                        <!--<span><a target="_blank" class="reply" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=<?php echo sanitize_text_field( $tweet_id ); ?>"><?php echo sanitize_text_field( $reply ); ?></a></span>-->
                    <span><a target="_blank" class="reply" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=<?php echo sanitize_text_field( $tweet_id ); ?>">Justin</a>
                                        <span><a target="_blank" class="retweet" href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=<?php echo sanitize_text_field( $tweet_id ); ?>"><?php echo sanitize_text_field( $retweet ); ?></a></span>
                                        <span><a target="_blank" class="favorite" href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=<?php echo sanitize_text_field( $tweet_id ); ?>"><?php echo sanitize_text_field( $favorite ); ?></a></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            }
        endif; /* End check if array $tweets empty or null */

        /* After widget (defined by themes). */
        echo ent2ncr( $after_widget );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can unregister the other widget. Although I don't quite get what you want to do.

Comment: That isn't a bad idea. I'm trying to customize that widget without overwriting that one. It's part of the theme the client purchased.

Comment: Ok I see. If your widget will be the main one and the other widget will never be used then I think you can safe unregister the widget after theme setup. Can't you disable the widget from the widget area inside admin panel or from Customizer ?

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not able to comment yet, I can only answer. But I've got questions. How does the widget get used? Where is it called? is the ORIGINAL script you posted above in a file like /theme/twitter-widget.php? Or is it in your functions.php script for the theme?

Something wasn't configured to run YOUR widget, and WordPress is still using the original.

Comment: The original is added by the parent theme functions file and the new one is added by the child theme in the functions file. Both by a PHP include.